# MapBox dosn't change renderAnnoations when update state in react native ( setState(..) , forceUpdate() have no effect to it )

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I change render annotations in my Mapbox every onPress call of one of the data filters buttons, as you see in this code :

```
import MapboxGL from "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps";

MapboxGL.setAccessToken("mytoken_workign_fine");

export default class myClass extends Component{
  render_annotaions1 = [{.....},{.....},....];
  render_annotaions2 = [{.....},{.....},....];
  render_annotaions3 = [{.....},{.....},....];
  
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        filter_state: 1,
      };
    }
  
  press_filter1(){
    if(this.state.filter_state != 1){
      this.setState({filter_state:1});
    }
  }
  
  press_filter2(){
  if(this.state.filter_state != 2){
    this.setState({filter_state:2});
  }
  }
  
  press_filter3(){
  if(this.state.filter_state != 3){
    this.setState({filter_state:3});
  }
  }
  
  getAnnotations(){
  switch(this.state.filter_state ){
    case 1:return this.render_annotaions1;
    case 2:return this.render_annotaions2;
    default:return this.render_annotaions3;
  }
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <MapboxGL.MapView
                  ref={(c) => (this._map = c)}
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  rotateEnabled={false}
                  logoEnabled={false}
                  userTrackingMode={1}
                  pitchEnabled={false}
                >
                  {this.getAnnotations()}
                  <MapboxGL.Camera
                    zoomLevel={1.1}
                    followUserLocation={false}
                    centerCoordinate={[9, 34]}
                  />
                </MapboxGL.MapView>);
  }
}
```

now, default annotations ( annotations1 ) is showing well, but when I press on one filter button, no map changing, it keeps default annotations and this is my problem, I want to change set annotations by news assigned annotations returned by **getAnnotaions()** every

> setState()

and

> forceUpdate()

call (the both are not working ), please I need help with this problem, and thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

When using `class` components in React, you need to bind the methods in the constructor in order to access `this`. Read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        filter_state: 1,
      };

      this.press_annotation1 = this.press_annotation1.bind(this);
    }
```

You need to do this for each click handler.

I would also recommend using a single click handler that takes in the filter state. Something like:

```
  setFilterState(annotationNumber) {
    this.setState({ filter_state: annotationNumber });
  }
```

Lastly, always name your React components with a capital letter.

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer,  all events handlers are working fine without binding and all my filtres methods are calling when I need, I need just how can I apply the required annotations change on my Mapbox.